# How to decode this string that Beautifulsoup process it?

Tags: javascript, python, html, string, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML document that has javascript in it, using re.findall I was able to get the arguments of the function I would need to convert them to a Beautifulsoup object.

The problem is that BS can not recognize the encoding of the string so I have a result that looks like this:

```
\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22table\x22\x3e MY DATA \x3c/div\x3e
```

I have tried different solutions like decode, etc. but still no solution.

**EDIT :**
when I manually pass the string as str = r"\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22table\x22\x3e MY DATA \x3c/div\x3e" Beautifulsoup is able to decode it, but once extracted from regex the string remains coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your string when pasting it. You can parse it similar to this

In js

```js
    const res = `\\x3cdiv class\\x3d\\x22table\\x22\\x3e MY DATA \\x3c/div\\x3e`
    .split('\\x')
    .slice(1)
    .map(v => {
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(v.slice(0, 2), 16)) + v.slice(2)
    }).join('')


    console.log(res)
```

In python

```py
def map_func(v):
    return chr((int(v[0:2], 16))) + v[2:]


txt = "\\x3cdiv class\\x3d\\x22table\\x22\\x3e MY DATA \\x3c/div\\x3e"
arr = txt.split('\\x')
arr = arr[1:]
print(''.join(map(map_func, arr))
```

Comment: Thank you, but i am using Python not Javascript for this.

Comment: moved the same code to python. Hope this helps

Comment: This is the solution, thank you very much !

Comment: Hello again, trying your solution for a few time, but i found that the final string still have characters like this : \ud83d\udca1 . Any solution on this please ?